# Python3 list expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Imagine I have this dictionary in python:

```
dict = {'arr': [{'prop1': 'foo'}, {'prop1': 'bar'}]}
```

And I want to change the 'prop1' values of all the items in arr to 'foobar', I could go like this:

```
for item in dict['arr']:
    item['prop1'] = 'foobar'
```

But I would like to know if there is a way to do this using a list expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, but only if you replace the *whole dictionary* each step:

```
dict['arr'] = [
    {k: 'foobar' if k == 'prop1' else v for k, v in d.items()} 
    for d in dict['arr']]
```

This assumes you have other keys in those dictionaries. If you don't, just generate new dictionaries with that one key:

```
dict['arr'] = [{'prop1': 'foobar'} for _ in dict['arr']]
```

Personally, if all you are doing is updating *one* key-value pair in the dictionaries, just stick to your original `for` loop.

Comment: good to add that this is because a list expression always returns a new list.. so if you want to update the variable, you need to overwrite the whole thing